# Prediction works on file, not on live stream

Tags: opencv, video-capture, video-encoding

We are trying to detect certain actions on videos by concatenating together a few consecutive frames and training a machine learning model. Our trained model predicts perfectly when we read from a file (webm, VP09 if it matters) but when we read from a stream, the predictions are completely off.

Experimenting, we found that the incoming stream (h264) is in "Raw YUV" format. So we tried to convert the frames to RGB and then grayscale. The numpy array looks OK in that some grayscale values are consistent with those areas in the image but the predictions are still off.

Is it not possible to simply take concatenated frames from OpenCV's VideoCapture's read and use them? We are novices at video streams and codecs, so is there something obvious that we are missing? Thanks!

Comment: It is impossible that the h264 stream is in "**Raw** YUV" format, but it's not the issue... OpenCV's VideoCapture converts the frames to BGR format. Convert BGR to grayscale using `cv2.cvtColor`. It's unlikely that the issue is BGR vs RGB. For testing, try to record the incoming stream to a video file, and execute the original code on the recorded video.

Comment: We have done what you suggested, which is how we found that when we work with files, the predictions are perfect. It is only when we try to grab and work with frames from the stream that we have the problem.

Comment: Are you grabbing from the file using OpenCV's VideoCapture? You are probably missing something simple (unless there is a real-time issue). Make sure that the `dtype` of the array is the same in both cases.

Comment: Yes, we are, and I will check. By real-time issue, I assume you meant the frame may not contain the complete information to construct a numpy array. Is that what you mean?

Comment: By real-time issue I mean that you are missing frames, because the framerate is faster than the processing time. For testing the correctness of the input, you may save the processed frames using `cv2.imwrite`. I don't think I can help you any further, your posted question is too general.

Comment: post data and code. narrating what was actually done leads nowhere.

Comment: Rotem, thanks, will do as you suggest and get back if it is unresolved. I don't think we are missing frames because we have viewed the frames, but I will re-check. Christoph, I can edit the code and post it. Unfortunately, I can't share the data since it is confidential, sorry.

Comment: then it might be a good idea to come up with data that you *can* share. you are asking people to debug your problem without looking at inputs or outputs (or even the code!). that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Christoph, we have severe legal restrictions on what we can share, else I would have been liberal in sharing data. This post was not on debugging. It was on whether there is something really fundamental that we being novices have missed. Rotem's answer suggests that that is not the case. After we resolve it, I will edit the post and provide the answer too.